# how to get specific and limited checked data from firestore database to angular4 autocomplete input

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

basically, I want to get limited data from firestore to use for autocomplete. I use a way that is:  "to get all data from the database and string match that data" but this method is too slow. Basically, I stored data like this
table->id's -> data.
I want to write a query that retrieves data for example: if I write a word in input autocomplete the query would get the 5 to 10 specific values and on second input words it again runs and gets more specific from firestore.
The conclusion is that I want to match string on real time from firestore to autocomplete input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. 
and the solution was so simple

```
searchArea(start){
  const end = start + '\uf8ff';
  return this.afs.collection('areas', ref => 
    ref
      .orderBy('title')
      .limit(5)
      .startAt(start)
      .endAt(end)
  ).snapshotChanges();
}
```

server-side API code to filter with a very fast and quick response.